# format a string the contains '%' golang

Tags: string, go, string-formatting, qsqlquery

I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT name FROM sessions WHERE name ILIKE 'org_name.%';
```

but I'm actually interested in replacing 'org_name' with format string (%s).
I was trying to do something like this:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT name FROM sessions WHERE name ILIKE '%s.%'", "org_name2")
```

but go seems to not like it, since writing %' isn't valid as format string.

I know I can solve it with do it in that way:

```
orgName := "org_name2"
condition := fmt.Sprintf("%s", orgName) + ".%"
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT name FROM sessions WHERE name ILIKE '%s'", condition)
```

but, I'd rather not, since the variable here is solely the org_name.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documented in the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) package, a literal `%` can be represented by `%%` in a printf format string:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT name FROM sessions WHERE name ILIKE '%s.%%'", orgName)
```

But be aware, you should ***NEVER, EVER*** build your SQL queries this way!  You are potentially opening yourself for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  Instead, you should pass parameterized arguments:

```
query := "SELECT name FROM sessions WHERE name ILIKE ?"
rows, err := db.Query(query, orgName + ".%")
```

Answer (score 1):

In go it is just `fmt.Printf("%s is how you write a %%", "This")`

https://play.golang.org/p/RIJKRADYzCk